# Goal Completions not displaying the right number using Google Analytics add on for Google Sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, add-on

On the Google Analytics dashboard, it's showing goal completions correctly (it appears). However, when I try to pull them with the Google Sheets plugin, they show as zero. I'm trying to see goal completions per ga:pagePath.

Goal Conversions returns the right numbers when used with other dimensions. However, with the page path, it is returning 0. Can someone please help? this is really frustrating.

For more reference,

```
Metric used: ga:goalCompletionsAll
Dimension: ga:pagePath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ga:goalCompletionLocation` dimension instead of *pagePath*.